# EF6 Seed method dropping references

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I'm using EF6 code first and I'm trying to add some test data in the seed method. I'm using an object that is self-referencing. The reference is optional so that top level elements have a null ParentOrgId. The OrgId is an identity column so I don't set the ids for it. The first time I run update-database the objects get added correctly and the ParentOrgId is correct. The second time and any subsequent times that I run update-database all the ParentOrgIds get changed to null. I have to delete the entries from the db and then again it will work the first time and then the second time they get changed to null. Any idea why it's dropping the references?

Object:

```
public class Org
    {
        public int OrgId { get; set; }
        public int? ParentOrgId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Depth { get; set; }

        public virtual Org ParentOrg { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Org> Children { get; set; }
    }
```

Configuration:

```
public OrgConfiguration()
    {
        HasKey<int>(o => o.OrgId);

        HasOptional<Org>(o => o.ParentOrg)
            .WithMany(o => o.Children)
            .HasForeignKey(o => o.ParentOrgId);
    }
```

In the seed method:

```
        Org[] seedOrgs = new Org[4];
        Org o1 = new Org();
        o1.Name = "TEST";
        o1.Depth = 0;
        seedOrgs[0] = o1;

        Org o2 = new Org();
        o2.Name = "TESTC1";
        o2.Depth = 1;
        o2.ParentOrg = o1;

        seedOrgs[1] = o2;

        Org o3 = new Org();
        o3.Name = "TESTC11";
        o3.Depth = 2;
        o3.ParentOrg = o2;
        seedOrgs[2] = o3;

        Org o4 = new Org();
        o4.Name = "TESTC2";
        o4.Depth = 1;
        o4.ParentOrg = o1;
        seedOrgs[3] = o4;

        context.Orgs.AddOrUpdate(o => o.Name, seedOrgs);
```

Answer (score 1):

This may be due to a [known bug](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework6/issues/23) in `AddOrUpdate`:

> A query for an entity that matches is performed which, if one exists, will return a new entity instance. (...) The instance passed into the AddOrUpdate method is essentially discarded. However, the application code is still using this discarded instance, which leads to the kind of unexpected behavior seen in this bug.

I would try this:

```
Org o1 = new Org();
o1.Name = "TEST";
o1.Depth = 0;
context.Orgs.AddOrUpdate(o => o.Name, o1);
o1 = context.Orgs.Local.Single(o => o.Name == o1.Name);
```

Then *don't add* `o1` to `seedOrgs` and execute the rest of the code.

By the way, you can also do

```
context.Orgs.AddOrUpdate(o => o.Name, o2, o3, o4);
```

Comment: I think you may be onto something with that bug, but even with those changes the references still get dropped on the second update-database.

Answer (score 0):

If you inserting a data using the Seed() method its best to let the class that contain the Seed() method (usually Configuration) inherit from :

```
DropCreateDatabaseAlways<YourContext>
```

this way your database will be deleted and created again each time you start your program thus you will get fresh new wanted data each time .

Comment: Sometimes I want to keep what's in there though. Not all data is entered with the seed method.